# style.top and style.left not working

Tags: javascript, css

I have a script written up that when a button is pressed, the formatdialog div gets resized.  The problem is that I can't figure out why my javascript code does not work. I am able to resize the width and height, but for whatever reason, the top and left can't be adjusted.

It doesn't make sense to me what could be causing a problem. Firebug doesn't give me any errors. The javascript just resizes the width and height and ignores the top and left attributes. I am guessing that the css properties are causing a problem, I just don't know what.

css:

```
#formatdialog {
            display:none;
            left:25%;
            top:25%;
            width:400px;
            height:200px;
            position:absolute;
            z-index:100;
            background:white;
            padding:2px;
            font:10pt tahoma;
            border:1px solid gray
        }
```

Javascript:

```
function FormatDialogResize(){
        var elem = document.getElementById('FormatDialog');
        elem.style.top = "10%";
        elem.style.left = "10%";            
        elem.style.width = "600px";
        elem.style.height = "500px";
    }
```

I also tried:

```
function FormatDialogResize(){
        var elem = document.getElementById('FormatDialog');
        elem.style.top = 10+"%";
        elem.style.left = 10+"%";           
        elem.style.width = "600px";
        elem.style.height = "500px";
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried positioning by px to see if it moves at all? Maybe the percentage calculation is off.

Comment: @n8wrl  I have tried using px also. I tried using "10px" and also 10+"px". Neither one changed the properties. I am testing in both FF and Chrome. I'm not sure how that would affect anything. I'd test on IE, but my windows box is OOC right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is you class name missing the pascal casing for the element ID  in the classId

```
#formatdialog {

FormatDialog
```

You have a typo.

The element id is **formatdialog**  but you are trying to call **FormatDialog**

```
var elem = document.getElementById('FormatDialog');
```

Your code should be like this:

```
<div id="formatdialog">

</div> 

var elem = document.getElementById('formatdialog');
elem.style.top = "10%";
elem.style.left = "10%";
elem.style.width = "600px";
elem.style.height = "500px";

#formatdialog 
{
    left:25%;
    top:25%;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
    padding:2px;
    font:10pt tahoma;
    border:1px solid gray;
    background-color:orange;
}​
```

If you want to use Pascal casing make sure it is the same in elementId and class

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/RDefp/1/)

Comment: I'm a little new to css. For whatever reason when I tried typing in the correct pascal casing, it would sometimes not work correctly. All lowercase works fine for whatever reason. I just tried returning my code to the correct Pascal casing. The styles still set the same. The top and left styles still do not work.

Comment: Unfortunately, the jquery route does not work. I've tried changing the casing, but that did not make a difference either. My gut is telling me that this is a js bug. It looks like I'll have to try to isolate the problem slowly to see what is causing it.

Comment: I have also give the javascript solution.. check that in the code above

Comment: Also when are you calling this function  FormatDialogResize()

Comment: Ahah! I found the problem. So the problem was that my webpage was ajaxing data from a separate page. This separate page had the FormatDialog on it. I moved the FormatDialog data to the main page and it worked. At least I'm not going (completely) crazy.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem and discovered that setting .top would not work until after I set the element to "position: absolute" .